# How I can get current container and package for my custom eclipse wizard plugin?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, package, containers, wizard

I maked a new eclipse wizard plugin.
My wizard ask for the container (source folder) and the package to create new java unit file.

How can I intercept current container and package selected, to pass to my plugin to precompile these fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Wizard class implements `IWorkbenchWizard` or one of the interfaces derived from that such as `INewWizard` then there is an `init` method which will be called immediately after the wizard is constructed.

```java
public void init(IWorkbench workbench, IStructuredSelection selection)
```

The `selection` argument gives you the currently selected UI element.